# WPF TabItem contents is not read by screen reader when custom ControlTemplate is applied to TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol, controltemplate, screen-readers

The ControlTemplate is taken from [Microsoft's website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752038(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="TabTemplate" TargetType="TabControl">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border BorderThickness="0,0,1,1" BorderBrush="#D0CEBF" Grid.Row="1">
                <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter ContentSource="SelectedContent"/>
                    </Border>
                </Border>
            </Border>
            <TabPanel Grid.Row="0" IsItemsHost="true"/>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<TabControl x:Key="TabTemplate">
    <TabItem Header="Header">
        <TextBlock Focusable="True" Text="Some text"/>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

If I remove `x:Key="TabTemplate"` from TabControl screen reader reads the content.

Should I add something to ControlTemplate to make it available for screen reader?

Comment: *If I remove x:Key="TabTemplate" from TabControl screen reader reads the content* - this seems to contradict the question title, removing the `x:Key="TabTemplate"` would actually apply custom template to your `TabControl`, then as the question title says, the screen reader ***cannot*** read the content, while you said *screen reader reads the content*.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I forgot to add `x:Key="TabTemplate"` I corrected the example code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="TabTemplate" TargetType="TabControl">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border BorderThickness="0,0,1,1" BorderBrush="#D0CEBF" Grid.Row="1">
            <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost" ContentSource="SelectedContent"/>
                </Border>
            </Border>
        </Border>
        <TabPanel Grid.Row="0" IsItemsHost="true"/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

The trick is the `x:Name` property of ContentPresenter. It should be exactly `PART_SelectedContentHost` for screen reader to behave correctly.